# Display issues with tables and .each block

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

I am trying to dynamically load a fixture list on my page, so i thought best thing to do was to use a table in this case rather than a list. My problem is that each table is rendering slightly different, they all need to mirror the first table in the screenshot

[image: My Form]

My code looks like so

```
<%= form_tag controller: 'predictions', action: 'create', method: 'post' do %>
 <% @fixture_date.sort.each do |date, fixture| %>
  <table>
   <h5><%= date_format(date) %></h5>
    <tbody>
     <% fixture.each do |fixture|%>
      <tr>
       <td><%= fixture.home_team %></td>
       <td><%= text_field_tag "predictions[][home_score]" %></td>
       <td><%= text_field_tag "predictions[][away_score]" %></td>
       <td><%= fixture.away_team %></td>
       <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][home_team]", fixture.home_team %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][away_team]", fixture.away_team %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][fixture_date]", fixture.fixture_date %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][fixture_id]", fixture.id %>
      </tr>  
     <% end %><!-- fixture -->
    <% end %><!-- date-->
   </tbody>
  </table>
 <% end %><!--Form Tag-->
```

Can anyone see anything glaringly obvious that i have missed out. The CSS is provided by Twitter Bootstrap and is set at their default values.. Maybe there is something wrong with the way i have set out the table?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tables are rendering correctly, the only different thing between them, is the width of your tds. Just set the width for each td in your css. For example, you can set the width in % and do something like:

```
table.fixtures {
    td {
        width: 40%;
        &:nth-child(2), :nth-child(3) {
            width: 10%;
        }
    }
}
```

This css is expecting your table to have 4 tds and is setting the width of 2nd and 3rd to 10% and the rest to 40%. (Also I used sass, but you can use plain css or less as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can have more control over the width of your table and cells by using this:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

It's hard to give a more detailed answer without a working example. You didn't post any CSS, and it's better to post the HTML that's sent to the browser.